# Hidden Field VS Database Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, hidden-field

I have a query that joins many tables (and is time consuming) and returns data to a view. 
I later want to pass this data from the view to another view. I know I can use a form with hidden fields to pass the data, or re-query the database in the controller of the second view.

I am wondering if there is a "preferred" way of doing this as far as efficiency and performance are concerned. Is it better to pass the data from the view to the controller using  a hidden fields? Or is it better to re-query the database in the controller to get the data?

Comment: How many columns are there and what is average result row count?

Comment: The main table has about 10 columns and it is joined to about 3 other tables with about 4 columns on avg

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields will pretty much **always** be faster than a database hit. You should leverage the use of them when you can, re-querying the database is one of the main benefits of using hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

IMO; You with 10 columns and it is joined to about 3 other tables with about 4 columns on avg it should not take considerable time.

You can create view and index the view for better performance.

I think it is better that you create a index view and use it to query on another control to get the live data from database. Because there are plenty of chances that once you load the data for the first time it may be change or new records may be inserted till the time you traverse to the next view.

So try creating view with index and you will fill the performance gain for sure.

Thanks,
Jigar